# Como impedir evento tanto para o pai, quanto para os filhos?

Tags: javascript

Estou com um codigo aonde somente caso o usuario click fora do containerNotification o container em si tenha display none. Porem ao clicar nos filhos dele o container fecha. como impedir tanto para o pai quanto para os filhos

```js
let notificationCtn = document.querySelector(".notification");

onclick = (e)=>{
   if (e.target != notificationCtn) 
            notificationCtn.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.notification{
padding: 30px;
background: blue
}
.notification div{
padding: 10px;
background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
<div>Zra</div>
<div>Zra</div>
<div>Zra</div>
<div>Zra</div>
<div>Zra</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo o seu raciocínio:

```
onclick = (e)=>{
  if (e.target != notificationCtn) 
    notificationCtn.style.display = "none";
}
```

O fragmento de código acima está instruindo ao interpretador que atribua a propriedade [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) do objeto global da página uma função como manipuladora de eventos. Deixando claro que o [objeto global](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Global_object) de uma página num navegador é o objeto [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window).

Sabendo disso fica fácil de entender que a todos os eventos click que ocorrerem na página foi atribuído um único evento que somente realiza uma ação caso a condição abaixo seja verdadeira.

```
e.target != notificationCtn
```

Ou seja `window.onclick()` somente realiza a ação `notificationCtn.style.display = "none";` caso o alvo do evento `onclick` não seja `notificationCtn`.

Como agora quer que os clicks nos elementos filhos de `notificationCtn` também não realizem a ação de esconder `notificationCtn`, use a propriedade [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), que retorna o nó pai do elemento, para detectar se o alvo do evento click é ou não parente `notificationCtn`.

```js
const notificationCtn = document.querySelector(".notification");

//onclick = (e)=>{ ... 
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target != notificationCtn &&
      e.target.parentElement != notificationCtn) {
    notificationCtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.notification {
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue
}

.notification div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
</div>
```

Essa abordagem não é a mais simples e a complexidade aumenta conforme adicionamos elementos a página.

Outra forma de obter o mesmo é adicionando o evento click ao container mais abrangente, no seu caso `notificationCtn`, e impedir esse evento de borbulhar usando o método [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```js
const notificationCtn = document.querySelector(".notification");

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  notificationCtn.style.display = "none";
});

notificationCtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue
}

.notification div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
  <div>Zra</div>
</div>
```